# Xcode Validate process and App Store app approval

Tags: app-store, xcode4.2

I have used the Validate tool in xcode and validated my application. The validation was OK and it says i could submit my app to appstore.

I need to know if the Validate process in xcode successful, does it mean my app is free from Private APIs and etc, and has 0 possibilities to get rejected when i submit my app to appstore for approval ?

Note: I am using xCode 4.2

Comment: You don't really need to add "beginner" to the title. All we ask is that you write a good question. And that you spell it correctly if you do ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not mean that at all.  It mostly means that it was signed correctly.  The only way to know that is to submit it, and wait for a response.

Also note: Your app could still be rejected for many reasons, not just for private API calls.

Comment: Where could i find a list of facts that will reject my app and is there any tool available that has the possibility to mimic apples testing process.\ ?

Comment: They do not publish this, because they do not want people to game it.  The best way, is to just submit it.  Also, if you have specific worries, search stack exchange for those worries.  People worry about topics like, subscribe outside of app, require account, show naked people, etc.  Each one has some answers.

Comment: @lllep : Apple's iOS Developer site has one list of reasons for rejections.  There is another list that is part of your Developer agreement.  There is no tool other than submitting an app and waiting for Apple's reply.